# How to access properties from an array prop's item in Vue 3

Tags: asynchronous, vuejs3, inertiajs, vue-props, vue-reactivity

I'm developing a project with Laravel 9, **Inertia** and Vue 3. When I provide a Collection of records from the database to a Vue page with Inertia, the values come as a prop, a Proxy **array of objects**, which I can check if `.length` is bigger than zero, I can check if `.every(i => i !== undefined)`, but **when I iterate over it**, it throws an uncaught in promise exception on console.

The ProfessionalsController.php

```php
/**
* Display a listing of the resource.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function index()
{
   $professionals = Professional::all();

   return Inertia::render('Professionals/Index', ['professionals' => $professionals]);
}
```

The Professional/Index.vue

```js
<script setup>
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { watch } from '@vue/runtime-core';

const props = defineProps({professionals: Array});

console.log(props.professionals, props.professionals.length, props.professionals[0].id);
</script>
<template>
    <Head title="Médicos" />

    <template v-if="professionals.length > 0 && professionals.every(i => !! i)">
        <ul >
             <li for="(index, professional) in professionals" :key="index">
                                    Nome: {{  professional.name }}<br>
                                    CRM: {{ professional.crm }}<br>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </template>
</template>
```

Here, the data comes. The `console.log` in the script, prints it.

```
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}, 7: {…}, 8: {…}, 9: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(10)
0: {id: 1, name: 'Carol Roque', crm: 'WN85149439', phone: '98775-0784', created_at: '2022-05-08T03:51:34.000000Z', …}
1: {id: 2, name: 'Diego Duarte Filho', crm: 'RU07697438', phone: '96712-3272', created_at: '2022-05-08T03:51:34.000000Z', …}
2: {id: 3, name: 'Dr. Ricardo Carrara Fidalgo', crm: 'CM55958226', phone: '97367-5229', created_at: '2022-05-08T03:51:34.000000Z', …}
3: {id: 4, name: 'Sr. Jorge Jean Romero', crm: 'NF71422476', phone: '93156-1833', created_at: '2022-05-08T03:51:34.000000Z', …}
4: {id: 5, name: 'Marta Galindo', crm: 'IB95085501', phone: '3048-2031', created_at: '2022-05-08T03:51:34.000000Z', …}
5: {id: 6, name: 'Dr. Lidiane Lia Ferraz', crm: 'PX86614139', phone: '2854-6792', created_at: '2022-05-10T03:53:15.000000Z', …}
6: {id: 7, name: 'Adriano Ícaro Ferminiano Neto', crm: 'KQ93046167', phone: '95618-8435', created_at: '2022-05-10T03:53:15.000000Z', …}
7: {id: 8, name: 'Dr. Erik Bittencourt', crm: 'YB92798968', phone: '90151-4721', created_at: '2022-05-10T03:53:15.000000Z', …}
8: {id: 9, name: 'Dr. Dayana Ortega Batista Neto', crm: 'RU93839397', phone: '91844-2628', created_at: '2022-05-10T03:53:15.000000Z', …}
9: {id: 10, name: 'Stefany de Aguiar', crm: 'UX32957687', phone: '99495-4536', created_at: '2022-05-10T03:53:15.000000Z', …}
length: 10
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

But when it comes **to the template, the items are undefined**:

```
app.js:23938 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

I even placed a `concole.log(professional)` inside the li tag, it only prints undefined

I'm guessing that although the `professionals` prop is reactive, it's items are not. But I can't find anything exactly about it, and no way of correcting that behavior.
*Already tried*:

- change to options api
- wrap professionals in a async/await arrow function in the v-for directive
- pass the prop.professional to a data state, using ref and asyncData
- extract the array from the Proxy with the value() method

Comment: Directive for [list rendering](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html) is `v-for` but you have only `for` in template. When used with array the first alias is an item and second alias is index - `(professional, index) in professionals`

Comment: Thanks MichalLevý! I think I should have just sleep sooner last night

Answer (score 1):

As Michal Levý mentioned, I was not using the correct Vue directive    `v-for` but only a `for` instead.

Also, I misplaced the alias for the index with the one for the object I was trying to access:

*before*

```html
<template v-if="professionals.length > 0 && professionals.every(i => !! i)">
    <ul >
        <li for="(index, professional) in professionals" :key="index">
            Nome: {{  professional.name }}<br>
            CRM: {{ professional.crm }}<br>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

*after*

```html
<template v-if="professionals.length > 0 && professionals.every(i => !! i)">
    <ul >
        <li v-for="(professional, index) in professionals" :key="index">
            Nome: {{  professional.name }}<br>
            CRM: {{ professional.crm }}<br>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

(actually I'm using `professional.id` as the key directive, but just to clarify, the order of the aliases was wrong too)